# REST: How best to handle large lists

Tags: rest

It seems to me that REST has clean and clear semantics for basic CRUD and for listing resources, but I've seen no discussion of how to handle large lists of resources.  It doesn't scale to dump an entire database table over the network in a resource-oriented architecture (imagine a customer table with a million customers!), especially if you only need a few items.  So it seems that some semantics should exist to filter, map and reduce a list of resources on the server-side.

So, do you know any tried and true ways to do the following kinds of requests in REST:

**1)** Retrieve just the count of the resources?
I could imagine doing something like `GET /api/customer?result=count`

Is that how it's usually done?

I could also imagine modifying the URL (`/api/count/customer` or `/api/customer/count`, for example), but that seems to either break the continuity of the resource paths or inflict an ugly hack on the expected ID field.

**2)** Filter the results on the server-side?
I could imagine using query parameters for this, in a context-specific way (such as `GET /api/customer?country=US&state=TX`).
It seems tricky to do it in a flexible way, especially if you need to join other tables (for example, get customers who purchased in the last 6 months).
I could imagine using the HTTP *OPTIONS* method to return a JSON string specifying possible filters and their possible values.

Has anyone tried this sort of thing?

If so, how complex did you get (for example, retrieving the items purchased year-to-date by female customers between 18 and 45 years old in Massachussetts, etc.)?

**3)** Mapping to just get a limited set of fields or to add fields from joined tables?

**4)** More complicated reductions than count (such as average, sum, etc.)?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm interested in how the request is formulated rather than how to implement it on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is OData! OData is a generic protocol for querying and interacting with information. OData is based on REST but extends the semantics to include programatic elemements similar to SQL.

OData is not always URL-based only as it use JSON payloads for some scenarios. But it is a standard (OASIS) so it well structured and supported by many APIs.

A few general links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Data_Protocol

http://www.odata.org/

Comment: Looks interesting.  OData does seem to allow filtering by an expression language, as well as other useful query options.  Seems a bit heavy as an approach, but it does seem to solve the problem of picking out the right resources without having to receive all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The most common ways of handling large data sets in GET requests are (afaict) :

1) Pagination. The request would be something like `GET /api/customer?country=US&state=TX&firstResult=0&maxResults=50`. This way the client has the freedom to choose the size of the data chunk he needs (this is often useful for UI-based clients).

2) Exposing a `size` service, so that the client gets to know how large the data set is before actually requesting it. The service would be something like
`GET /api/customer/size?country=US&state=TX`

Obviously the two can (and imho should) be used together, so that when/if a client (be it mobile or web or whatever) waints to fill its UI with content, he can choose what's the best data chunk size based also on the size of whole data set (e.g. to avoid creating 100 pages for the user to navigate).

Comment: So in the server endpoint controller you need to check whether the qualifier from the URL path is an ID or a keyword like "size", which seems like a slight disadvantage compared to  `GET /api/customer?country=US&state=TX&result=count`.  Is there an advantage to using the path instead of the query string to specify that you want the size?

Comment: well, the framework I usually use (Java's Jersey) handles that for you, so you specify two different endpoints : one is defined as `api/customer/size` and the other as `api/customer/{id}`, where `{id}` is a placeholder for a path parameter. I'm pretty sure most of the REST libraries and frameworks provide a facility for that distinction